# How can someone share a Reddit link onto Facebook while preserving the original title, with as little friction as possible?

Tags: facebook, links, reddit

Say, you post a thread like http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/t4d6d/how_do_you_share_a_reddit_link_onto_facebook/...

Then it shows up like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the shortlink -

[image]

That makes FB post like this -

[image]

Comment: What if I want to share a link to a specific comment? Doesn't look like there are short links for comments as well. Anyone knows a work around?

Comment: Yes. There is a work-around. Click share and select "Copy Link". Then before this link, add https://2fb.me/

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly handled by Facebook itself and there is not much you can do to fix this. What I would suggest is copying in the title and then putting some colon, and then add the link. For example:

> Check this post out:How do you share a Reddit link onto Facebook while preserving the original title, with as little friction as possible? (http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/t4d6d/how_do_you_share_a_reddit_link_onto_facebook/)

If you don't want the link to be so long you can use some url shortener such as:

https://bitly.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [Buffer](https://bufferapp.com) plugin. It is a plugin designed to help you stuff all of your social media posts on the Buffer app and then send them out at pre-selected times or just buffer them for later- so you don't tweet eightTEEN things at 4am.

The link to Buffer on Reddit shows up on the same bar as the other Reddit interaction links:

[image: buffer plugin on reddit]

It will generate the following popup which is the same for every buffer link:

[image: buffer popup on reddit]

And then you can click Share Now to post it immediately or Buffer to send it later.

I am pretty sure there are other browser plugins that accomplish the same thing, but the integration with Buffer is decidedly frictionless.

Answer (score 0):

Use the to Facebook web app.

https://2fb.me/https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/t4d6d/how_do_you_share_a_reddit_link_onto_facebook/

put the reddit link in full after https://2fb.me/